# Unset fields in Symfony form after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony project (2.7) I have a entity `Apartment`, with a lot of properties. One of them, is `Town`. 
`Town` is other doctrine entity, that they have a `City` entity, and `City` have a `State`.

In my `Apartment` form, I hace 3 selects. For `Town`, `City` and `State`. But when I want to save, I only want the `Town`.

```
...
$builder->add('town', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Town',
    'choices' => $towns,
    'class' => "AppBundle\Entity\Town"
));
$builder->add('city', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'City',
    'choices' => $cities,
    'class' => "AppBundle\Entity\City"
));
$builder->add('state', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'States',
    'choices' => $states,
    'class' => "AppBundle\Entity\State"
));
...
```

It's possible unset the extra fields that I don't want for saving the entity Apartment?

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        //I want to unset State and City entities. 
        $apartment = $form->getData();
        ...
    }
```

I have this error:

```
Neither the property "state" nor one of the methods "addState()"/"removeState()", "setState()", "state()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Apartment".
```

Comment: `$apartment->setState(null)`?

Comment: @Matteo, `$apartment` has no `setState()` method becouse not have to `state` attribute.

Comment: I can write `setState($state)` function but I think that is not the best way

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Do you have `state` class member within `$appartment`?

Comment: No, my class `$apartment` only have the `Town` class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once submitted, form data cannot be altered. But you could attach an event listener to do it just prior to submit finalization:

```
# Don't forget these
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

# ...

$builder->add('city', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'City',
    'choices' => $cities,
    'class' => "AppBundle\Entity\City",
    'mapped' => FALSE // <-- This is important
));

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event){
    $data = $event->getData();

    $data['city'] = NULL;
    $data['state'] = NULL;
    # We need this because of PHP's copy on write mechanism.
    $event->setData($data); 
});
```

If you need these to be `NULL`-ed before validation process, swap `POST_SUBMIT` for `SUBMIT`.

Now, call `form->getData()` within your controller will return `NULL` values.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but `$apartment` has not the `setCity` or `setState` methods. Only the `setTown`. I get this:

`Neither the property "state" nor one of the methods "addState()"/"removeState()", "setState()", "state()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Apartment".`

Because there are not `setState()` method

Comment: Ah, well, in that case, you need to mark your form fields with `'mapped' => FALSE`. Form fields which do not correlate to a entity fields must be marked as unmapped.

Comment: I have simplified the answer ;)

Comment: Correct! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually you can remove an event listener if you set `mapped=>false`. Because when you set mapped to false, that field will be ignored when reading and writing to an object. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped